# Function will not return a value after it calls itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, return-type

I just started learning Python a few days ago. I'm working on a chess game, and what I'm having trouble with is the code that determines the position of the piece the player wants to play. If I input a string with two numbers in it, the function parses them out and assigns them and the y and x value.

However, if only one or no numbers are found in the string, it prints "No digits or not enough digits found", lets you re-enter a string, and calls the function again. My problem is that after it calls itself, if you put in a valid string, it will identify the numbers, package it into a list like it's supposed to, but then won't return anything. I checked to make sure that the list is properly filled, and it is, it just returns none.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jack\PycharmProjects\Messing With 2D Lists\Messing With 2D Lists.py", line 91, in <module>
    piece_num = position[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is the code that calls the function, and the final line is the one that is triggering the error, because instead of a list it's receiving a none type:

```
posit = input("Choose your piece\nEnter coordinates: ")

position = piece_position(posit)

print(position)

piece_num = position[0]
```

Here is the "chess board" in case you want to reproduce my error because it's referenced in the code.

```
chess = [
    [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1],

]
```

And here is the function that determines the piece position:

```
def piece_position(pos):
    
    num1d = False
    num2d = False

    for char in pos:
        if not num1d:
            if char.isdigit():
                num1 = int(char) - 1
                num1d = True
            else:
                pass
        elif not num2d:
            if char.isdigit():
                num2 = int(char) - 1
                num2d = True
            else:
                pass

    print(num1d)
    print(num2d)

    if num1d and num2d:
        print(num1, num2)
        result = [chess[num1][num2]]
        result.append(num1)
        result.append(num2)
        print(result)
        return result
    else:
        print("No digits or not enough digits found")
        posit2 = input("Choose your piece\nEnter coordinates: ")
        piece_position(posit2)
```

Also I know that I call it as posit2 when it flips instead of just posit, and the variable is asking for the result of posit, but it doesn't seem to make any difference whether I change it to posit or posit2.

Feel free to make constructive organizational criticisms, again I'm brand new to Python and still figuring it out, I know I have lots to improve and lots I don't understand.

Comment: You just need to call the recursive function with a return statement: `return piece_position(posit2)`

Comment: @SerialLazer Thanks for the quick response! Where exactly would I put that? Would I need some index to mark whether it is the second or more time running, and if it is then return the recursive statement like you said?

Comment: Just add the return to the last line of your code where you are calling the recursive-function.

Comment: @SerialLazer Thanks, I realized just before you responded, I appreciate it!

Comment: Also, it would be better to use a while loop instead of calling the function within itself

Comment: @OneCricketeer So like `While not num1d or not num2d`? Edit: That seems to give me the same problem I had before, I'm probably just implementing it wrong.

Comment: After you define the variables, yeah, that'd work. Then the return statement will end the loop+function

Comment: @OneCricketeer I think my problem might be that doing it that way doesn't give me an opportunity to have the user input a new string, because I have no way of specifying in the function the new string that should be parsed through. (I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get None in the else statement that repeats the function, which you could return the function call result, or you could just use a while loop

```
def piece_position(pos):
    
    num1d = False 
    num2d = False

    while not num1d and not num2d:
        for char in pos:
            if not num1d:
                if char.isdigit():
                    num1 = int(char) - 1
                    num1d = True
            elif not num2d:
                if char.isdigit():
                    num2 = int(char) - 1
                    num2d = True
        if not num1d and not num2d:
            pos = input("Try again:") 
            num1d = False 
            num2d = False

    result = []
    #... 
    return result
```

Or, possibly simpler would be doing the same outside the function body rather than within (this way is definitely simpler to test)

```
pos = input("Enter coordinates") 
result = piece_position(pos)
while not result:  # assuming this returned None, or an empty list, for example 
    pos = input("Enter coordinates") 
    result = piece_position(pos)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! This all worked out for me, the only change I had to make to the adjustments you gave there was to reset both num1d and num2d to False after each loop in your first solution, because otherwise one might still be stuck as True and end up reassigning the new first digit as the second digit. I really appreciate your help on this and your suggestions to make it neater and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Although you've already solved, again: you forgot `return` on recursive call.

```
def func(n):
    ...

    return func(n')
```

Plus, why would one check if input is digit? That's nearly as bad as checking via `isinstance`. This is not *C*, we would rather ***not check it at all***.

If you're going to convert value to `int` anyway, then try it first, and catch error. That's called [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) style.

```
try:
    a = int('Nope.')  # try first
except ValueError:
    pass  # Fail, then that's a sad thing. Do some actions for this rouge cases.
else:
    pass  # We're good, keep going and do something with a.
```

Way simpler implementation would be this:

```
chess = [
    [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1],
]

def validate_position(board, pos: str) -> (int, int):
    try:
        x, y = map(int, pos.split())  # Fail-fast
    except ValueError as err:
        raise ValueError(f"Not enough / Too many values, expected 2!") from err

    # put some rule check here.
    if (0 <= x < len(board)) and (0 <= y < len(board[0])):
        return board[x][y], x, y

    raise ValueError(f"Position {(x, y)} is outside of board!")


def piece_position(board):
    inp = input("Enter coordinates (x y): ")  # Expecting 1 10 format
    try:
        return validate_position(board, inp)
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)
        return piece_position(board)


print(f"Selected: {piece_position(chess)}")
```

```
Enter coordinates (x y): 1 2 3
Not enough / Too many values, expected 2!
Enter coordinates (x y): 1
Not enough / Too many values, expected 2!
Enter coordinates (x y): 10 3
Position (10, 3) is outside of board!
Enter coordinates (x y): 2 3
Selected: (2, 2, 3)
```

If putting x, y coordinate at different `input()` call is absolute mandatory, change line as following:

```py
inp = input("Enter coordinates (x y): ")  # Expecting 1 10 format

# to 

inp = " ".join(input("Enter X: "), input("Enter Y: "))
```

---

As you've said that you're new to python, you'd better know the drawbacks of recursion in python. Neither of both applies to your use-case, but better know for future cases.

```py
>>> def recurse(called=1):
...     print(called)
...     return recurse(called + 1)
... 
>>> print(recurse())
.
.
.
985
986
987
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 3, in recurse
  File "<input>", line 3, in recurse
  File "<input>", line 3, in recurse
  [Previous line repeated 984 more times]
  File "<input>", line 2, in recurse
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Python does not perform tail-recursion optimization, and due to *CPython* stack limit, it will easily cause stack overflow and raise `RecursionError`. Of course one would never make a wrong input for around 1000 iteration, though.

Another drawback would be performance.

```py
from functools import lru_cache
import timeit


@lru_cache(512)
def fibo_recurse_cached(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1

    return fibo_recurse_cached(n - 2) + fibo_recurse_cached(n - 1)


def fibo_recurs(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1

    return fibo_recurs(n - 2) + fibo_recurs(n - 1)


def fibo_gen(n):
    a, b = 1, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b


print(f"Naive recursive : {timeit.timeit(lambda: fibo_recurs(38), number=10)}")
print(f"Cached recursive: {timeit.timeit(lambda: fibo_recurse_cached(38), number=10)}")
print(f"Generator ver.  : {timeit.timeit(lambda: list(fibo_gen(38)), number=10)}")
```

```
Naive recursive : 136.2449525
Cached recursive: 1.939999998512576e-05
Generator ver.  : 4.369999999198626e-05
```

If what you're doing inside recursion is simple and does not have any interaction with outer scope, then `functools.lru_cache` will drastically improve performance.

---

Comment: Hey this is amazing! Thank you for taking the time to write this out, I'm still reading through it but I really appreciate the effort you put into this. I will definitely take this into account.

Comment: One don't have to fall in pitfalls that others already did, at least on my watch: that's my faith. Taking a look at [python glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) will give you a good idea of Python's philosophy.

Comment: I will check that out thank you. I just finished reading through all of this and those are definitely important points about recursive functions. I'll have to re read that last one a couple times to make sure I understand it though. Also as OneCricketeer suggested I went ahead and rewrote it to fit in a while loop instead of using a recursive.